# Poisson generalized linear model (glm) sample size

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

Suppose I want to run a Poisson glm, what's the minimum sample size necessary to run it? Is there a formula to determine the minimum sample size for each unique statistical test?

Answer (score 2):

For Poisson glms, statistical power depends just as much on the size of the counts as on the number of count observations. Larger counts provide more precision, in fact the coefficient of variation of an observation is the inverse of the squareroot expected count size.

There is no minimum sample size, except that the number of observations should be at least as large as the number of coefficients in the linear predictor. The Poission distribution has no dispersion parameter, so there is no need to estimate variances separately to the linear predictor and, hence, no need for any residual degrees of freedom.

Note that each observation should correspond to a unique combination of predictor variables.
In a Poisson glm, multiple count observations with the same predictor variables will be summed to make a single observation.
The minimum sample size requirement therefore is that the number of unique predictor variable combinations should be at least as large as the number of coefficients.
If this condition is not satisfied then the linear predictor will not be estimable.

Depending on the glm, it is perfectly possible to get statistically significant results from just 2 observations, or even from 1 observation, provided the counts are not all small. 
Here is a small example in R with just two counts showing a significant trend with time.
First we fit the glm:

```
> Time <- c(1,2)
> Count <- c(1,10)
> fit <- glm(Count~Time, family=poisson)
```

A Wald test for the regression coefficient gives $P=0.028$:

```
> summary(fit)

Call:
glm(formula = Count ~ Time, family = poisson)

Deviance Residuals: 
[1]  0  0

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)    -2.30       2.02   -1.14    0.255  
Time            2.30       1.05    2.20    0.028 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance:  8.5472e+00  on 1  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: -8.8818e-16  on 0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 10.16

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

A likelihood ratio test for the regression coefficient gives $P=0.0035$:

```
> anova(fit, test="Chi")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: poisson, link: log

Response: Count

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

     Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)   
NULL                     1       8.55            
Time  1     8.55         0       0.00   0.0035 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```